# What do I need to change in the second "if" statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I cannot get the second number to be correct. There is something wrong in the "if" statement. Can anyone spot it? It works when I input `2 3 4 or 4 3 2` but not scrambled like **6 -5 4**. If I do **6 -5 & 4** then my output is **-5 -5 6**

```
import java.util.*; // imported scanner
public class ThreeNumbers{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter three floating-point numbers
        System.out.print("Enter 3 numbers separated by a space: ");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        int num3 = input.nextInt();


        // Display inputs in sorted order
        System.out.print("Sorted numbers: ");

        // Find the minimum number input by the user
        if ((num1 < num2) && (num1 < num3)) {
            System.out.print(num1 + " ");
        } else if ((num2 < num1) && (num2 < num3)) {
            System.out.print(num2 + " ");
        } else if ((num3 < num1) && (num3 < num2)) {
            System.out.print(num3 + " ");

        }
        // Find the middle number input by the user
        if ((num1 != num2) && (num1 != num3) && (num1 >= num2) && (num1 <= num2)) {
            System.out.print(num1 + " ");
        } else if ((num2 != num1) && (num2 != num3)) {
            System.out.print(num2 + " ");
        } else if ((num3 != num1) && (num3 <= num2)) {
            System.out.print(num3 + " ");

        }
        // find the maximum number input by the user
        if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3)) {
            System.out.print(num1 + " ");
        } else if ((num2 > num1) && (num2 > num3)) {
            System.out.print(num2 + " ");
        } else if ((num3 > num1) && (num3 > num2)) {
            System.out.print(num3 + " ");
```

Comment: what is expected output for 6 -5 4.

Comment: and post your full working code. half of the code is not helpful

Comment: `(num1 != num2) && (num1 != num3) && (num1 >= num2) && (num1 <= num2)` this is _never_ true. For starters.

Comment: Hint: If you find the smallest and the largest, add all three initial values and then subtract the previously found smallest and largest you are left with the middle value.

Comment: expected output for 6 -5 4 is -5 4 6. (Smallest to largest)

Comment: Another hint: I'd find Max/Min with `Math.Max(Math.Max(a,b), c)`. You can write this with `if`s , too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
if (((num1 >= num2) && (num1 <= num3)) || ((num1 <= num2) && (num1 >= num3))) {
        System.out.print(num1 + " ");
    } else if (((num2 >= num1) && (num2 <= num3))||((num2 <= num1) && (num2 >= num3))) {
        System.out.print(num2 + " ");
    } else if (((num3 >= num1) && (num3 <= num2))||((num3 <= num1) && (num3 >= num2))) {
        System.out.print(num3 + " ");

    }
```

Comment: I do not. Im trying to figure that out now. Still a beginner java student.

Comment: @hslomax You really should read all of the answers before ticking one accepted. This in particular would be considered a bad one. It works, but gives no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: I thing your idea is find them middle number in set 3 number. So in each if statement I check current number is >= one number and <= other number or not. ```||``` because 1st num > 3rd num or 1st num < 3rd num.

Comment: @Fildor It says to click the check if this answer solved my problem or if it was most helpful in finding my solution. I do want to know why it worked, and I'm trying to figure that out. But it solved my problem, so why not check it?

Comment: And [it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) goes on to say: _"Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question **well**."_ (emphasis by me) This is only a recommendation, of course.

Comment: Sorry two bros. I don't want to protect my answer but we should choose algorithm base on quantity and structure of input data. Our algorithms are O(1) because n = 3. I know Fildor want to suggest best practice and I want to focus on idea that I thing it's hslomax's idea.

Comment: @ThucNguyen No offense. I only think the answer is sub par because you throw in some code and say "try this". Add some explanation on why and where OP's code is wrong and why your solution gives the correct outcome and it'll be perfectly fine. Don't do it in comment but edit your answer. I'm sure it will be upvoted.

Comment: Thank @Fildor. Your comment is very valuable for me. I will try to explain more in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in comments:

```
// Find the middle number input by the user
    if ((num1 != num2) && (num1 != num3) && (num1 >= num2) && (num1 <= num2)) {
    // This is never true. If num1 != num2 , it cannot be >= AND <=
        System.out.print(num1 + " ");
    } else if ((num2 != num1) && (num2 != num3)) {
    // 6 != -5 and -5 != 4 => hit --> -5 ?? Logic Error!!
        System.out.print(num2 + " ");
    } else if ((num3 != num1) && (num3 <= num2)) {
        System.out.print(num3 + " ");
```

I'd suggest to use either Array.sort, Math's Min/Max methods or if you must use `if`:

```
int min = int.Max;
// unreadable:
//min = num1 < num2 ? (num1 < num3 ? num1: num3) : (num2 < num3 ? num2 : num3);
// still pretty bad:
if( num1 < num2 ){
  if ( num1 < num3 ) {
    min = num1;
  } else {
    min = num3;
  }
} else {
  if ( num2 < num3 ) {
    min = num2;
  } else {
    min = num3;
  }
}
// OR
int min = int.Max;
if ( num1 < min ) min = num1;
if ( num2 < min ) min = num2;
if ( num3 < min ) min = num3;
```

Respective for max, middle is the one, that is not min nor max:

```
int mid = num1+num2+num3-min-max;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think your problem may be with `(num1 >= num2) && (num1 <= num2)` because one of your conditions evaluate to `false` (i.e. 6 is >= -5, but not <= -5).

Why are you using `if` statements to do this, your implementation seems very complicated (especially if you suddenly want to input more numbers). Instead of all these `if` statements, just store each input into an array of integers, sort it and print it out.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter 3 numbers separated by a space: ");
  int [] inputNumbers = new int[3];
  inputNumbers[0] = input.nextInt();
  inputNumbers[1] = input.nextInt();
  inputNumbers[2] = input.nextInt();
  Arrays.sort(inputNumbers);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputNumbers));
}
```

Comment: I am using "if" statements per my assignment instructions.

Comment: Ah, Ok. No worries. Well the problem is the condition on your second set of if statements, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

For middle number, your first if condition is not correct use the below one and you will get your output

```
if ((num1 != num2) && (num1 != num3) && (num1 >= num2) && (num1 <= num3))
```

Comment: I changed it to what you said and I still get the same output. (input: 6 -5 4 ... output: -5 -5 6)